# Select list value undefined in $(document).ready

Tags: dom, jquery

I have the following code, which I want to load values on a selection change, and also do the selection load initially (since FF 'saves' the last value of the drop down under certain circumstances).

The select part of the function works correctly, but for some reason when calling `load2` directly the value of `$('#select1').value` is `undefined`, even though when I check the DOM in Firebug right after load `select1.value` has a value.

How can I run the `load2` function after `select1.value` is ready?  What event will tell me when all the elements of `$('#select1')` have been initialized?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Setup change hook 
    $('#select1').change(function(event) {
        //Remove the old options right away
        $('#select2').find('option').remove();
        //Load the new options
        load2(this.value);
    });

    //Do load for current value
    load2($('#select1').value);
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AFAIK the jQuery object does not have any `value` field. Hence, I would expect the following statement to pass a value of `undefined` to the `load2()`function:

```
load2($('#select1').value);
```

The jQuery object does, however, have a [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) function. Try using that instead:

```
load2($('#select1').val());
```

Alternatively, you should be able to access the DOM field `value` like this:

```
load2($('#select1').get(0).value);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand properly, you could check to see if a value exists, then run it:

```
if ($('#select1').value) {
    load2($('#select1').value);
}
```

Comment: The problem with that is that my second select list will not be populated, which is exactly what I was trying to do (populate that list).